# Problema de ruteo con Areas en ASP MVC2

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Estoy trabajando con ASP MVC2, he implementado "Areas" para seccionar mi proyecto pero estoy teniendo problemas cuando quiero acceder al controlador principal.

A continuacion les muestro la estructura del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

OK, ahora lo siguiente:
Corro el proyecto en Visual Studio, me abre al navegador y me muestra la 
pagina principal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El boton de la casita es para ir a la pagina principal, hasta aqui
todo bien, si le doy click a la casita me dirige a la pagina principal
porque cuando inicia la aplicacion se carga la ruta por defecto.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Nombre de ruta
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL con parámetros
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Valores predeterminados de parámetro
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

El codigo del boton de la casita es el siguiente

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Index","Home") %>" class="nav-link"><img src="../../Content/img/home.png" width="25px"/></a>
```

Este codigo es parte de una plantilla que tengo en la suiguiente ruta:

Proyecto\Views\Shared\Site.Master

**El Problema**

Si me dirigo a otra vista por medio del menu (he borrado los nombres de los menus para hacerlo mas sencillo) area 1 por ejemplo, estando en esa vista le doy
click a la casita, me da error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El programa me dirige a la siguiente ruta
Area1\Home\

cosa que me deberia dirigir a:
Home\Index 
de la pagina principal, entendiendo que la ruta por defecto es:
{Controlador}\{Accion}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo solucionar esto, esto pasa para todos los botones
que deberian redirigir a la pagina principal del proyecto.

Como nota final la pagina principal se encuentra en
**Proyecto\View\Home\Index.aspx**
De acuerdo al controlador principal por supuesto.

Las demas vistas de las areas:
**Proyecto\Area\Area1\View\vistaarea1.aspx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del `area` seguramente tambien tengas un `routing`

[Áreas en ASP.NET MVC – Una forma de organizar nuestras aplicaciones](https://diegobersano.com.ar/2015/01/05/areas-en-asp-net-mvc-una-forma-de-organizar-nuestras-aplicaciones/)

[asp.net mvc area](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/area-in-asp.net-mvc)

Como observaras en la imagen el `adminAreaRegistration.cs`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo como esto

```
public class adminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "admin_default",
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

deberia ser un `.cs` que este dentro de la carpeta del area.
Es por eso que las `Url.Action()` son aplican de forma contextual donde te encuentras

Si quieres que vuelva al principio o en algun area debes definirlo usando

```
Url.Action("Index","Home", new { Area = "" });
```

al indicar un area vacia indicas resuelva contra el routing que no indica un area

Comment: Voy a probar, espero que me funciones, gracias

Comment: puya me funciono, tenia ratos de querer resolver el problema, yo intentaba ponerlo asi: Url.Action("Index","Home", new { area = "Default"}) y no me funcionaba, jajaja solo tenia que dejarlo en blanco como tu dices, mil gracias me sacaste de un apuro grande, muchas gracias